# Gnu Emacs on Windows 7 very slow when VPN connection is used

Tags: windows-7, emacs, speed

I'm using Gnu emasc 24.3 on `Windows 7` and normally I don't have any problems with speed/responsiveness.

I'm launching `Emacs` with the `runemacs.exe`

However, when I am travelling and try to connect to my company network via VPN (or just working offline without a connection to the company network), Emacs often becomes incredibly slow - it might take many minutes to open a buffer and it just does not respond to keyboard commands.

All relevant text and configuration files are saved in my user directory **C:\Users\myusername.domainname\Documents** which is located on the local hard disk (so should not need accessing remote servers), but I wonder if Windows 7 might try to sync those files with a server

I'm also using the "offline files" feature for other directories and I wonder if this could have an effect on my problem.

---

EDIT: the problem occurs not only when VPN is used, but also when the computer is just offline and not connected to the company network.